# In Oracle how to join two tables one of the referred table column having with null values?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Let me explain the question in detail.
    I have 4 tables A,B,C,D.
    A,B,C are the tables having master data in which no row or column is null.
    But D is a mapping table using master tables A,B,C but having null values in some rows.

```
Now I wanted to join the 4 tables and display the output.

   An Example:

CREATE TABLE A
  (aid NUMBER,aval VARCHAR2(1)
  );
CREATE TABLE B
  (bid NUMBER,bval VARCHAR2(1)
  );
CREATE TABLE C
  (cid NUMBER,cval VARCHAR2(1)
  );
CREATE TABLE D
  (
    did NUMBER,
    aid NUMBER,
    bid NUMBER,
    cid NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (aid) REFERENCES A(aid),
    CONSTRAINT fk2 FOREIGN KEY (bid) REFERENCES B(bid),
    CONSTRAINT fk3 FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES C(cid)
  );
INSERT INTO A VALUES
  (1,'s'
  );
INSERT INTO A VALUES
  (2,'p'
  );
INSERT INTO B VALUES
  (1,'K'
  );
INSERT INTO B VALUES
  (2,'L'
  );
INSERT INTO C VALUES
  (1,'M'
  );
INSERT INTO C VALUES
  (2,'N'
  );
INSERT INTO D VALUES
  (1,1,1,1
  );
INSERT INTO D VALUES
  (1,2,NULL,NULL
  );
INSERT INTO D VALUES
  (1,1,2,NULL
  );
INSERT INTO D VALUES
  (1,1,NULL,2
  );
```

Now i want the output to be like:

```
s  K      M
p  null   null
s  L      null
s  null   N
```

I explained the edited question in the comment below.
  The exact query looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.NM,
  B.NM,
  G.NM
FROM w H
INNER JOIN A
ON H.id   = A.ID
AND H.FLG ='Y'
INNER JOIN F
ON F.ID  = H.ID
AND F.ID =1
INNER JOIN E
ON F.ID        = E.ID
AND E.BYu NOT IN ('7','1')
AND E.Dex      = 'A'
LEFT JOIN B
ON B.ID= E.ID
LEFT JOIN G
ON G.ID = E.ID
ORDER BY 1;
```

D table in my first post was the all the code or selection combined till left join of B.
  This query is working but I am not sure this is the best practise or not.
  I want to know how to filter a left side table in a left outer join before joining the tables( I don't want to filter it after using the where clause as it reduces the performance).
I also know that right side table in left outer join is filtered using "and clause in the join itself.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Outer joins (left or right in this case)? What have you tried?

Comment: @xQbert Thanks for your answer.I think i couldn't explain my query properly it is not this.I edited my question Please check.I have multiple tables some of which use inner join and some outer joins.I wanted to join tables after filtering some rows.When i am trying that the records are not getting filtered inside the outer joins.But i am able to  if i keep it in the inner join. i wanted to know what is the best practise followed in such a case and also how to filter records filter the records of E table.Please up vote my question as i am in the process of learning and earning reputation :)

Comment: Each database engine is different and versions are different.  Thus each engine will optimize a query differently.  When placement of filtering criteria doesn't effect the results, most modern engines will move criteria to the places that best benefit optimal performance; sometimes leaving them in where clauses sometimes applying them to results before joins occur.  So:  your question, "I want to know how to filter a left side table in a left outer join before joining the tables"  I typically do it in the where clause and let the engine optimize.  I also think it makes it more readable.

Comment: @xQbert That was a learning from me.I always try to do performance optimisation.It world be great if engines themselves arrange to get outputs in optimised way.I hope this question and comments would be a learning from all those who are novice in Oracle.Thanks to you for sharing your knowledge.Could you please up vote my question so that i could increase my reputation and participate in the chat rooms and other activities of stack overflow.I am very much interested in this site.It a great learning area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a simple outer join...

```
  select aval,bval,cval from d
  left join a on a.aid = d.aid
  left join b on b.bid = d.bid
  left join C on c.cid = d.cid
```

Maybe you need to read up on how joins work.  Here's a [great article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

and query with results.

[image]